# How do I enable filtering in my SAP UI5 SmartTable?

Tags: sapui5

My SAP UI5 view contains a [SmartTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable) that's bound to a regular entity set in my OData. The data shows fine and is formatted as intended.

I can sort the columns by pressing the column headers and when I press the table's "Settings" button (cogwheel icon), the menu allows me to choose sort options from a helpful list of columns.

[image]

However, when I switch to the "Filter" tab, all I get is an unhelpful tab with "Include" and "Exclude" sections that only show general "Field Name" and "Value" entries instead of offering me the table's columns for specifying filters:

[image]

What do I need to add to the OData or the SmartTable's properties to make this tab show a list of columns as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's missing was the [`filterProperty`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.table.Column#controlProperties) on the `sap.ui.table.Column`s that specify the SmartTable's look and feel:

```
<SmartTable ...>
  <Table ...>
    <columns>
      <Column 
          customData:p13nData="{
            leadingProperty: 'Version',
            columnKey: 'Version',
            sortProperty: 'Version',
            filterProperty: 'Version'  // <---
          }">
        ...
```